# How to retain element in list A that has been dragged from list A and dropped into list B using PrimeNg drag and drop?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a table and an unordered list in the same container. I want to drag the element from my unordered list and drop it into a table. When I do so, I want to still retain the dragged element in my unordered list. How do I retain the dragged element in the unordered list while using PrimeNg drag and drop feature?

I have implemented drag and drop feature using PrimeNg. The typical drag and drop is not going to help me since in typical drag and drop the item that you drag and eventually drop, gets removed from the list that contained it. Example - your unordered list contains details such as as first name, last name, DOB, gender etc. You dragged DOB from the unordered list and dropped it "employee" tabled. Now this drop effect results in removal of DOB from the unordered list and it results in addition of DOB in the employee table. This is what I am able to do, but that's not what I want. I want DOB to be still retained in my unordered list.

drag.component.html

```
        <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 drop-column" pDroppable="cars" dropEffect="link"
            (onDrop)="drop($event)" [ngClass]="{'ui-highlight-car':draggedCar}" >
            <p-table [value]="availableLeftColumnData">
                <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Question</th>
                        <th>MapID</th>

                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
                <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
                    <tr>

                        <td>{{car.total}}</td>
                        <td>{{car.question}}</td>
                        <td>{{car.mapid}}</td>

                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </p-table>
        </div>

        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-g-nopad drag-column">
            <ul style="margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;cursor:pointer">
                <li *ngFor="let car of availableCars" class="ui-helper-clearfix" pDraggable="cars" dragEffect="link" data-effect-allowed="link"
                    (onDragStart)="dragStart($event,car)" >

                    <div style="margin:8px 0 0 8px;float:left">{{car.mapid}} - {{car.question}}</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

drag.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import {CarComponent} from '../car/car.component';
    import { CarService } from '../service/CarService';
    import {SharedModule,DataTableModule} from 'primeng/primeng'; 
    //import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        DataTableModule,
       // TableModule
      ],

    })


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-drag',
      templateUrl: './drag.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./drag.component.css']
    })
    export class DragComponent implements OnInit {

      availableCars: CarComponent[];

      availableLeftColumnData:CarComponent[];

      selectedCars: CarComponent[];

      draggedCar: CarComponent;

      constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.selectedCars = [];
          this.carService.getCarsSmall().then(cars => this.availableCars = cars);
          this.carService.getCarsMedium().then(cars=>this.availableLeftColumnData=cars);

      }

      dragStart(event,car: CarComponent) {
          this.draggedCar = car;
          console.log(this.draggedCar);
          console.log(event);
      }

      drop(event) {

          if(this.draggedCar) {
              let draggedCarIndex = this.findIndex(this.draggedCar);
              let draggedCarMapid=this.draggedCar.mapid;
              this.selectedCars = [...this.selectedCars, this.draggedCar];
              this.availableCars = this.availableCars.filter((val,i) => i!=draggedCarIndex);
              this.draggedCar = null;
          }

      }

      dragEnd(event) {
          this.draggedCar = null;
      }

      findIndex(car: CarComponent) {
          let index = -1;
          for(let i = 0; i < this.availableCars.length; i++) {
              if(car.mapid === this.availableCars[i].mapid) {
                  index = i;
                  break;
              }
          }
          console.log(index);
          return index;
      }

    }
```

When I drag an element from the unordered list and drop it on the table, I want the dragged element to be still retained in the unordered list. That's not happening right now.
Eventually apart from the above thing, on the drop event I want to populate the "mapID" column with the mapid of the the element that I drag and drop onto the table.

Comment: Hi, jfranko! Currently its hard to grasp this amount of files you put to the question. Please, edit your question to shorten it to only minimum code needed to understand the point. You can set up a small project at e.g. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) and share a link to that project — it would be helpful for us when we'll need to understand the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code is removing (filtering out) the dragged item from the unordered list:

```
this.availableCars = this.availableCars.filter((val,i) => i!=draggedCarIndex);
```

If you want to retain the element on the list, you should remove this line of code.